# Оптимизация запросов к mysql

Tags: mysqli, mysql

Таблица состоит из нескольких полей, включая поле "content" (текстовое) и поле "category" (категория). В админке я бы хотел вывести отображение всех существующих категорий. Админу при выборе любой из них представляется список записей по данной категории. 
Изначально я сделал так, что скрипт "шерстит" всю базу данных по полю "category" с группировкой (GROUP BY) категорий и выводит этот список.

Задумался, а если записей будет много? И вопрос такой: не проще ли в данном случае создать еще одну таблицу CATEGORIES, которая будет содержать именно существующие категории? При добавлении в основную таблицу записи с новой категорией в таблицу CATEGORIES также будет вписываться это новое название категории.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше. Лучше вообще все дублирующиеся в ячейках строковые данные выносить в отдельные таблицы, тогда с БД при большом количестве информации будет приятнее работать и занимать она будет меньше места.

Comment: @Get, ну меньше места она точно не будет занимать.

Comment: @Deus нормализация, не слышали?

Comment: @smackmychi, меньше места база занимать не будет. Для каждого поля content все равно будет присутствовать поле category. База данных станет наоборот -  чуть-чуть больше, потому что я добавлю таблицу CATEGORIES. Зато выборка будет происходить намного быстрее.

Comment: @Deus, Почему интересно?
Или Varchar(0-255) размером 256 байт повторить 1000 раз или INT размером от 2 до 8 байт те же 1000 раз.

Comment: @Get, а, ну да. Только встречный вопрос: в таком случае, чтобы выбрать запись по данной категории, запрос будет к двум таблицам? Первая по имени категории выдаст ее  id_category, а уже по этому id_category из второй таблицы найдется нужный контент?

Comment: Если категорию искать по наименованию, то да, именно так. Но даже так это делается одним запросом с помощью JOIN, например. Вообще, при выводе категории для выбора так или иначе передается ее ID, так что ничто не мешает использовать сразу этот ID для последующей выборки.

Comment: @Deus почему вы отвечаете на мой вопрос уверенно, но не понимая смысла слова нормализация?

Comment: @smackmychi, откуда мастеру-штукатуру знать теорию БД? Теперь уже вспомнил. )) Я просто подзабыл, что лет 5 назад как раз об этом и читал, что вместо строковых дубликатов необходимо использовать INT.

Comment: @Deus суррогатный ключик, чтобы вы не запутались.